# Get a flatten JSON from an various Sails.js models associations

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have this hierarchy structure: `Person < has a > Team < has a > Department`

and I want to extract the flatten record from a person like this:

```
{ 
  "name": "Foo",
  "id": 1,
  ...
  "team": {
    "name": "MGMT",
    "id": 1,
    "department": 1
    ...
  },
  "department": {
    "name": "Top",
    "id": 1,
    "office": 1
    ...
  }
}
```

These are the models:

PERSON

```
// A person that belongs to a team
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    //Assosiations    
    team: {
      model: 'team'
    },
    department: {
      model: 'department',
      via: 'team.department'
    }, 
  }
};
```

TEAM

```
// A team with many persons and belongs to one department
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    //Associations
    department: {
      model: 'department'
    },

    members: {
      collection: 'person',
      via: 'team'
    }
  }
};
```

DEPARTMENT

```
// A department that has many teams
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    teams: {
      collection: 'team',
      via: 'department'
    }
  }
};
```

I'm can't do it like this (yes, it has more levels):

```
function (req, res) {

        Person.findById(1).exec(function (err, people) {
            Team.findById(people[0].team).exec(function (err, teams) {
                Department.findById(teams[0].department).exec(function (err, departments) {
                    Office.findById(departments[0].office).exec(function (err, offices) {
                        Company.findById(offices[0].company).exec(function (err, companies) {

                            var composeRecord = Object.assign(
                                people[0], {
                                    team: teams[0],
                                    department: departments[0],
                                    office: offices[0],
                                    company: companies[0],
                                });

                            res.send(composeRecord);

                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })  
    }
```

Any ideas how to do it better?

Comment: Write a database query and use [`.query`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mongo, you can do it using promises. It will look much better

```
var composeRecord
Person.findById(1).then(function(people){
    composeRecord = people[0]
    return Team.findById(people[0].team)
}).then(function (teams) {
    composeRecord.team = teams[0]
    return Department.findById(teams[0].department)
}).then(function(departments){
    composeRecord.department = departments[0]
    return Office.findById(departments[0].office)
}).then(function(offices){
    composeRecord.office = offices[0]
    return Company.findById(offices[0].company)
}).then(function(companies){
    composeRecord.company = companies[0]
    res.json(composeRecord)
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

If you are using reletional db like MySQL o PG you should write a  [query](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)

Comment: @FilipeMoraisJorge it works, but it would work faster if you write query with joins.

Comment: So I'm choosing between Agnostic to the DB or Faster execution. Thanks again.

Comment: You can also try [Offshore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offshore). Id supports deep populate. If you have proper keys your code wold look more like this Person.findById(1).populate('team').populate('department').populate('office').populate('company').then().catch()